# How to obtain the name of changed columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have enabled change tracking on a table, with `track_columns_update = ON`, but when I query the changes

```
SELECT
  CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION,
  CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS
FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES MYTABLE, 1408) AS CT
```

The result is this:

```
8B
00000000  00 00 00 00 25 00 00 00                            ....%...
```

Can I convert this somehow to the names of the table columns?